# how to split 'header', 'src', 'test' dir in cmake?(and donot add cmakelist.txt in each dir)

Tags: cmake

when building a project stucture like following:

```
LinearAlgebra
|---HEADER
|-----|---Linear.h
|---SRC
|-----|---Linear.cpp
|---TEST
|-----|---hello_test.cc
```

here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(LinearAlgebra )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

add_library(LA_HEADER INTERFACE header/Linear.h)
add_library(LA_SRC INTERFACE src/Linear.cpp)
target_include_directories(LA_HEADER INTERFACE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/header" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")


enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  test/hello_test.cc
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main
  LA_HEADER
  LA_SRC
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

it works fine with `cmake -S . -B build`, but when it comes to `cmake --build build` following error occured:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Linear::Linear()", referenced from:
      HelloTest_BasicAssertions_Test::TestBody() in hello_test.cc.o
```

it seems something wrong with my cmake file that didn't tell `Linear.h` where `Linear.cpp` located. So how to fix it ?? thanks for your help...

Comment: post the output of `cmake --build build --verbose`

Comment: still thanks, though i've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems i misunderstand `add_library`, change three lines and it works out:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(LinearAlgebra )

include_directories(header) # include_directories instead of add_library for .h files       
add_library(LA_LIB src/Linear.cpp) # use add_library for .cpp files only!!!

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  test/hello_test.cc
)

target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main
  LA_LIB # link LA_LIB only..
)


include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

leave it here for anyone have the same requirements.

Comment: You should also add the header files (as PRIVATE source) in your add_library() so IDE can catch it